# Possible to Retrieve Device's Phone Number Automatically In Android?

Tags: android, phone-number

Is it possible to retrieve device's phone number via the Android API(specifically 1.5 API).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the phone's phone number by calling the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29).

Note that you'll need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.